# how to display the checkbox in pdf

Tags: php

I'm working on a php(codeigniter) form that sends data to a PDF file when submitted. I can get value of a text field to populate corresponding field in PDF but don't know how to display checkbox in pdf. Can someone help please?

thanks
Ahammed

Comment: Presumably, the answer depends highly on *how* you create your PDFs.

Comment: ...and the number of answers you get depends on previously accepted ones. Look through your four old questions and accept some answer, if it helped (click the hook in the upper left corner of the answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because the form submitted to your application used a checkbox doesn't mean that your PDF has to have one. Afterall, it's just going to be a static representation of what was submitted. You have two immediately obvious options which don't require checkboxes

- Yes/No text
- Tick/Cross image

Answer (score 2):

If you create the pdf with mPDF, the cheched checkbox will be automatically rendered if you use the parameter
`checked="checked"`

This example works:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Service 1
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked="checked">Service 2
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">Service 3
```

See http://mpdf1.com/manual/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

You could, for one, include JavaScript in the PDF to generate the checkbox dynamically. Here is the JavaScript API: [PDF file](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf). Advantage: You can in the same JS instance add behaviour to the checkbox.

How to do this, however, depends on your used PDF framework.

If it's just for display purpose, go with icio's answer and embed simply a static image.